# Regex Working on regexr but not Visual Studio

Tags: regex

I am writing my first Regex replace string. I am using: http://www.regexr.com/ to test my Regex.

My goal is to find all classes that do not inherit from another class. For example:

Find:

```
class Test
{

}
```

Do not Find

```
class Test : AnotherClass
{

}
```

Also do not find

```
class Test;
```

I have managed this by using the following Regex

```
(class [^\s]+)\s{
```

I would like to find all these string in visual studio and replace with:

```
$1 : NewObject
```

Resulting in:

```
class Test : NewObject;
```

The problem is that though this code runs on http://www.regexr.com/ it does not run in Visual Studio.

The old version I had tried earlier works:

```
((?!.*:)class [^\n]+)\s{
```

But the problem with that is that it is inserting the : on the next line like so:

```
class Test
: NewObject
```

Any ideas what may be wrong with my Regex that it wont work in Visual Studio? Or perhaps new Regex that will do what I need?

Comment: (class [^\n| ]+)\s{ seems to work. Though it is still replacing the line after and not the same line as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason Visual studio doesn't seem to include newlines in `\s`.

As a workaround, here's a pattern that will work:

```
(class\s+\w+)([\s\r\n]*\{)
```

replace that with:

```
$1 : NewObject$2
```

And if you need generics support, use this instead:

```
(class\s+[\w\s<>]+?)([\s\r\n]*\{)
```